# Computer Freezing weird line and BSOD

Tags: freeze, bsod, crash

PC configuration:

- 4560 Intel dual core
- Gigabyte 110 motherboard
- Corsair Vengeance DDR4 4GB RAM

PC is 6 months old.

PC works for a while then freezes with weird lines and restarts with BSOD.
Formatted many times but issue still persists.

[image]

PC has been freezing/crashing at random times. Sometimes it freeze while booting or sometimes it boots okay and works for a while before freezing.

I have cleaned PC, disabled everything and reassembled everything but cannot locate the issue.

what could be possible issues?

Comment: This is most likely a hardware issue, although it could conceivably be a driver - most likely graphics driver - issue.

Comment: What does the blue screen message say, and have you tried testing/stressing each component?